# where to store the encryption key in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, security, encryption

I need to implement encryption in my iPhone app.
I will use [FBEncrytor](https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor) to do it. However I need to know where to store the encryption key.
Do I just `#define` it in a header and use it directly? or save it in the Keychain? or maybe in a static property?

What is the usual way of storing it?

Comment: hi check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535114/safe-way-to-save-encryption-keys-in-ios

Comment: What's "FBEncryptor"?

Comment: @trojanfoe edited my question to include the link. It is an encryption library that is build on CCCrypt and uses AES256

Comment: Wherever you store it, it's extractable ...

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp So what is the common way of doing it?

Comment: @Youssef asking the user for some password and deriving the key from it (you can use device-specific information to have longer key as the password is usually too short for a reliable key).

Comment: in define section or in plist

Comment: why not.. in Keychain?